# While getting OutofMemory Error, HPROF file size is less than Max memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory

My JVM initial Memory is 256 MB. Max memory is 512 MB. When I am getting OutofMemory error, created HPROF file size is less than 200MB. (Not all the time)
(It is difficult to analyze this small HPROF files. Because all Objects in HPROF took only small amount of memory)

Can anybody say why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

OutOfMemory errors may occur, if the heap has less space available, than required for the allocation of a new object. So even *if* the hprof file would be an *exact* copy of your memory, it would be naturally smaller than max memory.
But nonetheless, hpref *is not* an exact copy of the memory, but a representation of it's state, same as a thread dump is not an exact copy of your CPU state, but a representation of it.

Comment: Thanks for your info

Answer (score 0):

How do you analyze the hprof file? Some tools do not show the amount of memory that is held through references.

You should open and analyze the hprof file with a profiling software like [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). There you could find the objects with the references that are holding the most amount of memory by opening the "Dominator Tree"

Comment: I used Eclipse Memory Analyzer for analyzing HPROF. I am saying about whole HPROF file size(Not object size).